# How can I convert this "for" loop to use EOF in C?

Tags: c, string, loops, eof

```
char* readScores(int* actualCount) {

char* stringArray = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

for(int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
    *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
    scanf("%s", &stringArray[i]);
    printf("stringArray = %s when i = %d\t actualCount = %d\n", &stringArray[i], i, *actualCount);
}
printf("Finished!");

return stringArray;
}
```

With this code I am looping through a .txt file with some words inside. When I run this code, I see that I am indeed getting the correct words in the correct places in the array, but as soon as the loop reaches the end of the file the program gives me a segfault error. I'm guessing that this is because the loop is hitting the EOF value and throwing an error, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here is a screenshot of the results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B73x1.png

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

I changed my code to this:

```
while(scanf("%s", &stringArray) != EOF) {
    *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
    printf("stringArray = %s when actualCount = %d\n", &stringArray, *actualCount);
}
```

However, I'm still getting a segfault error with the same output values. So I know it's reading the file correctly, I just don't get why it stops at the end and throws an error.

Comment: Code can use the return value from `scanf()`, but a better approach uses `fgets()`

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do? As written, it reads multiple words from standard input, returns a pointer to the last one, and sets `&actualCount` to the number of words read (assuming you pass in a pointer to an `int` with an initial value of 0).

Comment: This particular function is supposed to do just that. The program as a whole reads the file counts how many occurences there are of each word, then sorts them by number of occurences. What I can't figure out is why it's giving me an error.

Comment: I think it'll actually return a pointer to a string consisting of the first characters of all the strings except the last one, and then the last one.

Comment: Why would it be doing that? Am I missing something with regards to how scanf works? How can I change it?

Comment: @Nannooskeeska: Keith already explained this - you're missing something with regards to how `malloc()` works. The corrected version merely better writes the code you used - it's not the code you ought to be using. Right now you create one array, write the first string to it, then write the next string at the second element, overwriting all the characters of your first string except the first one, and so on with the rest. If you want an actual array of strings, you'll need to create one.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: The updated code doesn't do that; it overwrites `stringArray` from the beginning on each iteration.

Comment: @Nannooskeeska: That doesn't make sense. To count occurrences of words, you need to save *all* the words you read. Your function reads multiple words, but it overwrites each word when it reads the next one.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The code in the edit does that, you're correct.

Comment: In general, the `scanf(...) != EOF` test is not appropriate, though for the `%s` format, it will work.  You should get into the habit of using `scanf(...) != 1` where 1 is the number of values you expect.  With numeric conversions, you can get back 0 instead of EOF when you're scanning for a single number but there is punctuation or alphabetic data as the next character.

Comment: Also if you wait to be taught each function that you ever use, you will never be able to program usefully.  You can look up the manual for `fgets()` very easily; it is not hard to use.  In that, it is very unlike `scanf()` which is damn near impossible to use correctly and is a cruel and (regrettably not) unusual punishment when inflicted on novice programmers — `scanf()` is endlessly subtle and tremendously devious.

Answer (score 2):

You want to continue looping as long as `scanf` successfully reads a word from standard input.

So the termination condition for the loop should use the result returned by `scanf`.

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully read. It will return `1` if it successfully read a word, and either `0` or `EOF` otherwise.

But there are some other problems with your code.

```
char* stringArray = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

This doesn't allocate space for 100 strings, or even for 100 pointers to strings. It merely allocates space for a single array of 100 `char`s. And it's better written as:

```
char *stringArray = malloc(100);
```

Casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary and can mask errors, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Your `for` loop reads successive words into memory starting at position 0 in the allocated array, then at position 1, then at position 2, etc, with each read overwriting part of the previous one.

Also, `scanf` with a `"%s"` format is inherently unsafe, since it will read as many characters as the user types (or from whatever `stdin` is connected to), regardless of the size of the target array.

It's safer to use `fgets()` to read lines of text, and then perhaps `sscanf` to parse the input (though `sscanf` has some of its own problems).

And if you want to store multiple strings, you'll need to allocate space for them. I'm not certain enough about what you're trying to do to offer more specific advice.

Comment: Check out my edit. We haven't learned how to use fgets() yet, so I'm not going to use it here. I'm also not worried too much about stuff like the malloc issues unless they affect the end result, so I'm not going to change them. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: You'd better worry about the `malloc()` issues, unless you want to be frustrated with this program for a long time. It'll break the whole purpose of your function if you don't.

Comment: Ok, I changed the `malloc()` to your version, but I'm still getting a segfault.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: The `malloc` call isn't exactly incorrect. The cast and the multiplication by `sizeof(char)` aren't wrong, they're just unnecessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I think his `malloc()` call is incorrect in that it doesn't do what he wants, unless both calling his variable `stringArray` and the original use of `&stringArray[i]` are red herrings and he only wants to retain one of the words, which would make it difficult to count and sort them later.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` is generally a poor function to use, but, as gleaned from the comments, if you insist on using it, the following code does what I presume you want to do, here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** create_string_array(const size_t num_strings, const size_t maxlen) {
    char ** new_array = malloc(num_strings * sizeof(*new_array));
    if ( new_array == NULL ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory for string array.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_strings; ++i ) {
        new_array[i] = malloc(maxlen);
        if ( new_array[i] == NULL ) {
            perror("Couldn't allocate memory for string.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return new_array;
}

void free_string_array(char ** array, const size_t num_strings) {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_strings; ++i ) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}

char ** readScores(int* actualCount) {

    char ** stringArray = create_string_array(14, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; ++i) {
        int status = scanf("%s", stringArray[i]);
        if ( status == 0 || status == EOF ) {
            break;
        }
        *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
        printf("stringArray = %s when i = %d\t actualCount = %d\n",
            stringArray[i], i, *actualCount);
    }
    printf("Finished!\n");

    return stringArray;
}

int main(void) {
    int num_strings = 0;
    char ** stringArray = readScores(&num_strings);

    printf("There were %d strings read. They are:\n", num_strings);

    for ( int i = 0; i < num_strings; ++i ) {
        printf("%2d: %s\n", i + 1, stringArray[i]);
    }

    free_string_array(stringArray, num_strings);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and with a suitable datafile outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ cat data_file
Twas
brillig
and
the
slithy
toves
did
gyre
and
gimble
in
the
wabe
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ cat data_file | ./strcount
stringArray = Twas when i = 0    actualCount = 1
stringArray = brillig when i = 1     actualCount = 2
stringArray = and when i = 2     actualCount = 3
stringArray = the when i = 3     actualCount = 4
stringArray = slithy when i = 4  actualCount = 5
stringArray = toves when i = 5   actualCount = 6
stringArray = did when i = 6     actualCount = 7
stringArray = gyre when i = 7    actualCount = 8
stringArray = and when i = 8     actualCount = 9
stringArray = gimble when i = 9  actualCount = 10
stringArray = in when i = 10     actualCount = 11
stringArray = the when i = 11    actualCount = 12
stringArray = wabe when i = 12   actualCount = 13
Finished!
There were 13 strings read. They are:
 1: Twas
 2: brillig
 3: and
 4: the
 5: slithy
 6: toves
 7: did
 8: gyre
 9: and
10: gimble
11: in
12: the
13: wabe
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Keith already pointed out the fundamental errors you had, namely, if you need a dynamic array of strings, then you need to `malloc()` memory for an array of pointers to `char *`, and then for each one, `malloc()` memory for the string itself, which your original code does not do, and you need to be checking the return from `scanf()` for `0` and `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your for loop with a while loop.

```
while (fgets(buffer, buffer_size, fp)) {
    // do something with buffer
}
if (ferror(fp)) {
    // handle the error, usually exit or return
} else {
    // continue execution
}
```

Comment: That's not C, though.

Comment: sorry about that kinda read through it fast. Think its time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* readScores(int* actualCount) {
    char* stringArray = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    int i=0, len;
    while(scanf("%s%n%*c", &stringArray[i], &len)==1){
        printf("stringArray = %s when i = %d\t actualCount = %d\n", &stringArray[i], i, ++*actualCount);
        i += len + 1;
    }
    printf("Finished!");

    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you have offered has no issue. Neither myself, nor my MSVC on Windows got any troubles in working with it. Here's how it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main( )
{
    FILE * asd;
    char* stringArray = calloc( 100, sizeof(char) );
    int actualCount = 0;

    freopen_s( &asd, "wsx.txt", "w+", stdin );

    fprintf_s( stdin, "this is a test this is only a test this also is a test" );
    rewind( stdin );

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 13; i++ ) {
        actualCount = actualCount + 1;
        scanf_s( "%s", &stringArray[i], 100 - i );
        printf_s( "stringArray = %s when i = %d\t actualCount = %d\n", &stringArray[i], i, actualCount );
    }
    printf( "Finished!" );

    Sleep( 5000 );
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is as you'd expect it to be, with no errors... So my answer is that the problem you are experiencing is due to something other than the code you've written.

Comment: 1. Including `<Windows.h>` in your answer is slightly bad taste, here; 2. "The code you have offered has no issue" is clearly not true; 3. Your code uses `fscanf_s()`, a totally different function than the one the OP's code uses, you can't really claim that "the code you have offered has no issue" on the grounds that you compiled different code and didn't find a problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths _**OPINIONS**_ [...] Seriously though, `Windows.h` is for `Sleep`, _you_ have a bad taste if you say it is a bad taste. They can be omitted, nonetheless. Rest is simply false accusations...

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour by writing to the file and then immediately reading from without an intervening positioning operation (`fseek()` et al) or `fflush()`. Your `fscanf_s()` most probably gets EOF because the file position is at the end of file.  You can't tell whether it worked because you don't test its return value.  Your test data is not longer than 100 characters, so some of the problems are not triggered.  And for this code, the acid test is printing the data in the 'string array' after the loop.

Comment: Also, you are misusing `fscanf_s()`; when you use a `%s` format, you have to provide two arguments: the character pointer and also the maximum allowable length to be stored in the pointer. The call should be `if (fscanf_s(asd, "%s", &stringArray[i], 100-i) != 1) …report error…`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I also had realized that this afternoon and changed it over here. Corrected it here as well.

Comment: Add a loop like `for (i = 0; i <= 13; i++) printf("%d [[%s]]\n", i, &stringArray[i]);` after the main loop and before the `Sleep()` to see what's wrong with the whole basic algorithm.